# Сопоставить два датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['1, 2', '2, 2','3, 2','1, 1', '2, 1','3, 1']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 100, 'x'], [3, 4, 200, 'y'], [5, 6, 300, 'x']])

df22 = df2.rename(index = lambda x: x + 1).set_axis(np.arange(1, len(df2.columns) + 1), inplace=False, axis=1)

f = lambda x: df22.loc[tuple(map(int, x.split(',')))]
df = df1.applymap(f)
print (df)

Output:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  2  4  6  1  3  5
```

df1 содержит значения 'строка, столбец'  ('1, 2', '2, 2','3, 2').
Я пытаюсь найти по этим значениям значение в df2. Например, 1,2 это первая строка, второй столбец, это 2 в df2.

То что пытаюсь сделать: умножить полученное занчение на занчение из 3 столбца соответствующей строки и добавить x или y. `(2*100x, 4*200y, 6*300x, 1*100x, 3*200y, 5*300x)`

На выходе пытаюсь получить 5000(сумма всех x и y), 0.28 (1400/5000 - % y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вы намудрили с задачей и с исходными данными. Непонятно, зачем вам вообще нужен df1, если ы все равно перемножаете и суммируете все столбцы.

Можете сначала для наглядности сгруппировать фрейм по `x` и `y` так:

```
res = df2.groupby(3).apply(lambda x: x[0]*x[2] + x[1]*x[2]).to_frame()
```

теперь в res у вас:

```
        0
3        
x 0   300
  2  3300
y 1  1400
```

Далее простая арифметика:

```
total = res[0].sum()
y_pct = res.loc["y"][0].sum()/total
print(y_pct)
print(total)
```

```
0.28
5000
```

Comment: спасибо, за ваш вариант решения!